# SUM row group by name using pdo

Tags: php, mysql

Kindly help me correct following code.

```
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT SUM(quantity) from tblorders GROUP BY itemname" or die(mysql_error());
$query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$cnt=1;
if($query->rowCount() > 0) {
    foreach($results as $result):              
    ?>  
        <tr>
            <td> <?php echo htmlentities($cnt);?></td>
            <td><?php echo htmlentities($result->itemname);?></td>
            <td><?php echo htmlentities ($result->quantity);?></td>
       </tr>
    <?php 
    $cnt++;
    endforeach;
}?>
```

as I am not able to get sum group by itemname.

Comment: You're using PDO, which is great. That also means `mysql_error` has no business being in this code and won't give you any useful information anyway, it's an unrelated library.

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT SUM(quantity) from tblorders GROUP BY itemname" or die(mysql_error());` will die and print the mysql error if the string assignment fails?

Comment: okay, but what is wrong with the code, as I am not getting sum of quantity, please guide me.

Comment: [From the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) *PDOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by the last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement executed by the corresponding PDOStatement object.* in your case you have a select so `rowCount` wont tell you anything probably. You just need to do `count($results)` instead This is only one of your problems though.

Comment: So what is the other way out to get the sum of group of particular itemname. As I am not getting the sum of quantity but itemname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following:

Just notice that I have fixed sql for you.

```
<?php 
    $sql = "SELECT itemname, SUM(quantity) AS quantity from tblorders GROUP BY itemname";
    $query = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
    $results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $cnt=1;
    if($query->rowCount() > 0) {
        foreach($results as $result) { ?>  

        <tr>
            <td> <?php echo htmlentities($cnt);?></td>
            <td><?php echo htmlentities($result->itemname);?></td>
            <td><?php echo htmlentities ($result->quantity);?></td>
        </tr>

<?php 
            $cnt++;
        } 
    }
?>
```

Comment: Great! Thanx a tone, I think I missed minor thing... which is actually critical.